# python - import subpackage from a package not working?

Tags: python, import, package

I have the following files:

```
pack/__init__.py
pack/subpack/__init.__py
pack/subpack/mod2.py
```

And the following code fails on the last line:

```
from pack import * #should import everything
print subpack      #NameError: name 'subpack' is not defined
```

I would expect the subpackage to be imported - why is there a difference, and how can I overcome it?  **Important:**  by "overcoming" I mean being able to refer to `subpack` without needing to write `pack.subpack` all the time.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add

```
__all__ = ["mod1", "subpack"]
```

to `pack/__init__.py`.  Without this line, `mod1` would not be imported either, so I wonder what is going on there.  See also the [relevant section in Guido's tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about doing `from subpack import *`. It only says that you want to do `from pack import *` and refer to `subpack` rather than `pack.subpack` (which could be easily accomplished by `from pack import subpack`).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but afterwards I still cannot do `from subpack import mod2` which is what I want to do (`from pack.subpack import mod2` would work of course).
You are right about mod1, I edited the question and removed it; sorry.

Comment: @Velociraptors - I wouldn't want to explicitly write `from pack import subpack` - I have tons of modules and packages inside `pack` and I am trying to do something similar to c++'s `using` statement.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question or your previous comment (which appears to have been deleted).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "import subpack" in `pack/__init__.py`

If you have `__all__` declared, make sure 'subpack' appears there.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative suggestion for Python 3 is:

```
# pack/__init__.py
from . import subpack
```

And, as already was mentioned, if `__all__` is declared, then add `'subpack'` here.

And do not forget, that if you need NOT only:

```
print subpack
```

but also:

```
print subpack.mod2
```

then you need make similar operations in `pack/subpack/__init.__py` file